# why mybatis update and delete are not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am developing a microservice using myBatis but UPDATE and DELETE statements are not working in it.
Even simple update statements are not executing whenever I execute it just stuck and no response

```
<update id = "update" parameterType="map">
        UPDATE TESTDB 
             SET
                <foreach item = "entry" index = "key" separator = "," collection = "SET">
                     ${key} = #{entry}
                </foreach>

            WHERE
                <foreach item = "entry" index = "key" separator = "AND" collection = "WHERE">
                     ${key} = #{entry}
                </foreach>

    </update>
```

calling function

`session.update("test.update",map);`

map contains SET and WHERE keys and values as per json request given below

As I am using PUT method so my json request which I am putting in maps such as SET and WHERE.

```
{
"data":
[   
    {
        "set":
        [
            {
                "ID":"2",
                "NAME":"abc",
                "TYPE":"abc"
            }
        ],
        "where":
        [
          {

                 "NAME":"a",
                 "ID":"1"
          }
        ]
    }
]

}
```

I am getting correct query in logs but when I execute it through POSTMAN I am getting these,
It shows that it's sending and loading and doesn't execute just stuck that it's sending but no response.

This issue is with only delete and update query rest are working fine.

[POSTMAN REQUEST SENDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibk9y.png)

Comment: Can you once try hardcoding the query in update fragment?

Comment: I already tried with simple update query but results are same it just stuck for update and delete queries rest are working fine

Comment: @EshuYadav A common reason for such issue is that another session locks the row(s) you are trying to update or delete.

Comment: @EshuYadav does update statements work when you execute from some other tool like SQLDeveloper?

Comment: @Smile Yeah from SQLDeveloper those update queries are executing fine.

Comment: Enable the debug logging for MyBatis and check detailed logging.

Comment: @Smile Thanks for help. I got reason why it was failing. I have create a SqlSession and that session is being used by all operations and that session locks the row which I am trying to update or delete.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Smile.

I got reason why it was failing. I have created a SqlSession and that session is being used by all operations and that session locks the row(s) which I am trying to update or delete.

**Solution:-**

1. Make separate session for all operations.
2. Check whether session is null or not make it null if it points to
   some other previous session and assign new session in it using sqlSessionFactory so that it won't locks the rows(s).